# Parse a String to a char?

Tags: java, string, char

So in Java how is it possible to pase a String like ("\u000A") to a char?
I got that String from a file, so i can't say something like this: 
char c = '\u000A';

Comment: `char theChar = theString.charAt(0);`

Comment: Note that if the literal text `\u000A` is appearing when you dump a string you read from the file, it means that you did not read the file with the correct character set translation.

Comment: @HotLicks there is a chance on earth that OP needs to make that translation.

Comment: No i need that char(s) - it is the correct character set translation.
But i am wondering about:
`String theString = "\u0029";
char theChar = theString.charAt(0);
System.out.println(theChar);`
It Works - but shouldn't it return just a '\'?

Comment: There seems to be some confusion if the data is a string of length 1 (i.e. Unicode escape in Java string literal) or a string of length 6 (i.e. text read from a file) - take time to clarify. (Note: `"\u000A".length()` is 1, even though it is "6 characters" in the literal form.)

Comment: Right.  Do System.out.println of the string's `length()` to see what you have.

Answer (score 3):

Check [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html)

> > Escapes and unescapes Strings for Java, Java Script, HTML and XML.

This should work for what you want

```
char c = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava("\\u000A").charAt(0);
```

Double back slash is to encode "\u000A" in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, this is perfectly valid code:

```
char c = '\uD840';
```

The example in your code, `'\u000A'` happens to be a non-valid Unicode character (probably a decoding problem when reading?). But all valid Unicode characters can be passed along between single quotes.

Comment: (Keep in mind that 0x0A is newline, and hence will produce a new line if you attempt to print it.  But it's a perfectly valid character.)

Comment: It won't compile because it looks like a newline in the middle of a string constant.  This is BECAUSE it's a valid Unicode character.

Answer (score 0):

Without extra libraries, you can use the fact that this is just the hexadecimal value of the char. This expression's value is that character:

```
(char)Integer.parseInt(input.substring(2, 16))
```

The technique works even for surrogate pairs because then you'd have two separate \u notations for the pair.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to Oscar Lopez, this compiles and executes just fine:

```
public class TestUnicode {
    static public void main(String[] argv) {
        System.out.println("This is one line"); \u000A System.out.println("This is another line");
    }
}
```

The important thing to understand is that, in the Java compiler, `\uXXXX` characters are translated *as the programs is being scanned*, not as the characters are being inserted into a string literal (which is the norm for other `\` escapes).  Replace the `\u000A` above with `\n` and the program will not compile, but rather the compiler will report "Illegal character: \92" (and 92 is the decimal value for `\`).